# Pushing elements to array

Tags: reactjs

From what I have been able to gleam from the Internet, this function should work. However, babel fails to compile it citing a invalid token. If I comment out the push lines everything works.

Can someone help me out with the correct syntax to do this?

```
renderSuggestionText(highlightText, text) {
  const fragments = [];

  let buffer = text;
  while (buffer.length > 0) {
    const fragmentStart = text.toUpperCase().indexOf(highlightText.toUpperCase());
    if (fragmentStart > 0) {
      fragments.push(<span>{buffer.substr(0, fragmentStart)}<span>);
      fragments.push(<span className="bold">{buffer.substr(fragmentStart, highlightText.length)}</span>);

      buffer = buffer.substr(fragmentStart + highlightText.length);
    } else {
      fragments.push(<span>{buffer}<span>);
      buffer = '';
    }
  }

  return fragments;
}
```

Comment: And which token is Babel complaining about? `<`? In that case it seems you haven't loaded the React presets for Babel. See https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/language-tooling.html#productionizing-precompiled-jsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error on some of the span tags. You need to make sure you close all of your tags (`<span></span>`) For example:

```
} else {
  fragments.push(<span>{buffer}<span>);
  buffer = '';
}
```

Babel will always throw an error if you fail to close all of your tags. Should be something like "Unterminated JSX .."

should read:

```
  fragments.push(<span>{buffer}</span>);
```

Comment: grr. Silly mistake. Thanks!